# Using python tempfiles, why is .SpooledTemporaryFile giving me errors when .mkstemp works fine

Tags: python, temporary-files, sox

Im trying to write some code to first process two audio samples using sox transformer, then combine the two audio files using sox combiner. Im also trying to do the processing first in memory to speed things up.

I am getting this error when using `.TemporaryFile()` and `.SpooledTemporaryFile()` but it works fine when using `.mkstemp()`:

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "...", line 128, in <module> generate_new_audio_files(user_library_folder_pathlist, new_folder_path, file_count) File "...", line 101, in generate_new_audio_files combine_two_files_mild(sample1_file_path, sample2_file_path, new_folder_path, count) File "...", line 30, in combine_two_files_mild _, sample1_audio = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`

Here is my code:

```
def combine_two_files_mild(file_path_1, file_path_2, parent_folder_path, count=None):
    combiner = sox.Combiner()
    tfm1 = sox.Transformer()
    tfm2 = sox.Transformer()
    tfm1.set_input_format(rate=44100)
    tfm2.set_input_format(rate=44100)
    combiner.set_input_format(channels=[2, 2])
    combiner.gain(normalize=True)
    # will eventually insert here some randomized settings for the two transformers

    # this determins the file category based on it's file name
    file_main_category, file_sub_category = Category.get_file_category(file_path_1)

    sorted_file_folder = parent_folder_path + "/" + file_main_category + "/" + file_sub_category
    new_file_path = sorted_file_folder + "/" + file_sub_category + " Combined " + \
                                                        str(count + 1) + " Mild.wav"

    # load the audio data for the two samples
    _, sample1_audio = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
    tfm1.build(file_path_1, sample1_audio)
    _, sample2_audio = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
    tfm2.build(file_path_2, sample2_audio)

    # combine the two files and write to disk
    combiner.build([sample1_audio, sample2_audio], new_file_path, 'mix-power',
                   input_volumes=[0.5, 0.5])

    # clear the 'memory'
    os.remove(sample1_audio)
    os.remove(sample2_audio)
```

Comment: Please include the actual stack backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

The API for `SpooledTemporaryFile` is different from `mkstemp`. `mkstemp` returns a tuple of two objects (which you are setting as `_` and `sample1_audio` respectively).

`SpooledTemporaryFile` [will return a single file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) for you to use. Usually `SpooledTemporaryFile` and `TemporaryFile` are used as context managers like so:

```py
with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as sample1_audio:
    tfm1.build(file_path_1, sample1_audio)
```

Note that after the `with` block, the temporary file will be deleted, so either keep all of your code that requires the temporary files in this block, or you can manually handle the file opening and closing yourself:

```py
sample1_audio = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
tfm1.build(file_path_1, sample1_audio)

... # Other stuff you want to do

sample1_audio.close()
```

Additionally, the `tempfile` module is specifically made to create temporary files which are removed automatically when they are no longer needed, so you should not need your calls to `os.remove` at the end!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the `sox` module, so I can't say for sure whether or not tfm1.build(...) will be happy to accept this file object, but I assume it will!

Comment: Hmm yeah I can see thats not going to work, as the moment I remove the _, and make it just sample1_audio = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(), the tfm1.build() complains. tfm1.build() is basically asking for an input and output file path string, not an object. I get the following error: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not SpooledTemporaryFile"

Comment: Again, I'm not very familiar with `sox`, but from looking quickly at the docs, there's a `build_array` method on sox.Transformer which looks like it will do the same thing as `build`, but it will return an in-memory array to you instead of saving to a file if that's what you're interested in. You could then save that output array separately.
https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=build#sox.transform.Transformer.build_array

Comment: Yeah this is what I will ultimately do, however once the individual files have been processed, I want to combine them with sox combiner. Per the docs, combiner can only combine files from 'disk' with strings of their filepath and then out to disk, it cannot combine arrays. So im looking for a way to create a 'fake' .wav file in memory with a file path that can be used with both sox transformer and combiner in place of a 'real' file on disk.